# How to insert a column in one dimensional NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a NumPy array

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
```

I want to insert a new column to `A` to make it look like

```
A=[[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [1,5], [1,6], [1,7], [1,8], [1,9], [1,10], [1,11]]
```

I tried using `NumPy.insert(A,0,1,axis=1)` but it gives following error:

> AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

I can't find where I am doing wrong. Please help me rectify this and suggest any other method(s).

Comment: Do you understand that `A` has only 1 dimension?

Answer (score 1):

[np.insert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) insert only single value, you need to stack a second column. you can use [np.column_stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) or [np.c_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html)

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
arr1 = np.ones(len(A))
out = np.c_[arr1,A]
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  7.],
       [ 1.,  8.],
       [ 1.,  9.],
       [ 1., 10.],
       [ 1., 11.]])
np.column_stack((arr1,A))
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  6.],
       [ 1.,  7.],
       [ 1.,  8.],
       [ 1.,  9.],
       [ 1., 10.],
       [ 1., 11.]])
```

Comment: `insert` can add a column, but you have to start with a 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

The `column_stack` or `array` that others suggest are fine, but to stick with the `insert`:

```
In [126]: A = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])                                               
In [127]: A.shape                                                                                      
Out[127]: (10,)
In [128]: A[:,None].shape                                                                              
Out[128]: (10, 1)
In [129]: np.insert(A[:,None],0,1, axis=1)                                                             
Out[129]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 1,  3],
       [ 1,  4],
       [ 1,  5],
       [ 1,  6],
       [ 1,  7],
       [ 1,  8],
       [ 1,  9],
       [ 1, 10],
       [ 1, 11]])
```

To do an insert on axis 1, `A` has to have such an axis, i.e. has to be 2d.  That's what your error message was all about. `A` is only 1d.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
b = np.ones(a.shape[0])
c = np.array((b,a)).T
```

Output is:

```
[[ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  2.]
 [ 1.  3.]
 [ 1.  4.]
 [ 1.  5.]
 [ 1.  6.]
 [ 1.  7.]
 [ 1.  8.]
 [ 1.  9.]
 [ 1. 10.]
 [ 1. 11.]]
```